# Using Windows Forms in Visual Studio with C#, is there a way to get the Graphics.DrawEllipse function to draw the ellipse exactly as specified?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, graphics2d

I'm learning C# and graphics programming using Windows Forms for Visual Studio, and I'm running into a problem where calling DrawEllipse and passing a rectangle the size of the window causes the ellipse to go outside of the window on the right and bottom sides.

Here is the code that draws the ellipse:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 40));
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(0, 150, 0)), new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
    }
```

When this code runs, it produces the following result:
[Ellipse drawn in window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vge6w.png)

I've already tried setting the window size in the Form1_Load function, which didn't change anything. 
Is there some property I should be changing at some point? I find it hard to believe `this.Width` and `this.Height` don't actually match the dimensions of the window. Has anyone else run into this problem before?

Comment: See the difference between a Form/Control `Size` and its [ClientSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.clientsize) and [ClientRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle). You should also check out the [PreferredSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.preferredsize) property (the Docs don't really provide much informations about it - none, actually - but it becomes quite important in a ScrollableControl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are getting when you use `Form.Width` and `Form.Height` is the dimensions of the Form including the non client areas. Try using [`Form.ClientSize.Width`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.clientsize?view=netframework-4.8) and `Form.ClientSize.Height`.

I.e.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 40));
    e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.FromArgb(0, 150, 0)), new Rectangle(0, 0, this.ClientSize.Width-1, this.ClientSize.Height-1));
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, what purpose do non-client areas serve?

Comment: Usually it’s used for the window chrome.

Comment: http://www.equestionanswers.com/vcpp/client-non-client-area.php